# How to concatenate values of two fields with update cursor with ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, cursor, null

I have a small block of code where I concatenate two date fields and use field calculator to calculate a the values of a third field.  My date fields are `ORIGDTDATE` and `ORIGDTTIME`.

How can I change the block of code that is below to concatenate the fields if the value for the row in emergency_overdue is NULL?

```
import arcpy     

calcExpression =  "!ORIGDTDATE!+\" \"+ !ORIGDTTIME!"
```

arcpy.CalculateField_management(self.line_ticket_feature_class,"emergency_overdue",calcExpression,"PYTHON_9.3")

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management(self.poly_ticket_feature_class,"emergency_overdue",calcExpression,"PYTHON_9.3")
```

Comment: Select by attribute, apply 1st, switch selection, apply second. I would replace it with da. Update Cursor, works much faster

Answer (score 1):

You can create an [update cursor](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/updatecursor-class.htm) with a where clause for only rows where emergency_overdue is null. The code below is a straight concatenation of the date and time fields, you may want to use a separator like `"ORIGDTDATE" + ":" + "ORIGDTTIME".`

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(self.line_ticket_feature_class, ["ORIGDTDATE", "ORIGDTTIME", "emergency_overdue"], "emergency_overdue IS NULL") as ucur:
    for row in ucur:
        row[2] = row[0] + row[1]
        ucur.updateRow(row)
```